# Solutions for backing-up my codebase

Tags: source-code, aws, backup, github

I have a codebase that I've been keeping on Github that I don't want to worry about losing. I've intermittently backed up all the repos to an S3 instance, but this doesn't feel secure. If my Github and AWS accounts, or just my machine, were compromised then our entire codebase & its backups could be deleted.

What can I do to protect against this? I'm having a difficult time finding solutions which guarantee that I won't have to worry about an account being compromised and everything being subsequently deleted.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about your use case but what is the problem with having local backups, i.e. external hard disk, tape etc? Can you please explain your actual requirements in more detail?

Comment: General advice on backups is to use the 3-2-1 rule: three copies, on at least two different media, one of which is offsite. If you use a cloud service for storing backups, enable 2FA.

Comment: The standard advice for this is "backups" and "2FA".

Comment: @FireQuacker: ... and keep the offsite copy at least 50 km away from your home :) So that in case of earthquake, flooding or similar it remains safe.

Comment: Send a copy to NSA. They will keep it for you forever. And for free.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich A requirement would be not allowing any account to delete files until a set date and not allowing any account to change this config in any matter that would allow them to be deleted before that date

Comment: @ZachWild: all of this could be done with offline backups (external disks, tape, ..) as I've already pointed out. And you still did not explain why this is not an option although I've explicitly asked.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Off-lining backups would seem to solve my concerns about them being deleted

Comment: @mentallurg yah, but the recovery process is pretty slow a it will occasionally come back with half the content redacted.  Also, no sending required ... they prob already have it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have your code in GitHub, consider creating mirrors at other providers.

Assuming the GitHub repository is the "main" one your work with:

- **GitLab:** Create a mirror at GitLab and configure [automatic pulling](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html) from GitHub. Why is it good? You configure it once, then you can relax, the mirror will be updated automatically.
- **BitBucket:** In the free version it supports only automatic pushing, not pulling. Bug look at GitLab again, it can both. Configure [automatic pushing](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html) from GitLab to BitBucket.
- **DropBox or similar:** Create a local copy of your repository in your DropBox folder and periodically pull from the main repository.

Thus effectively you will have your code at 4 different platforms.

Comment: Also might want to consider  using diff email accounts and diff ssh keys such that if one is lost to you, you can still get in with another.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider running an SSH server on the machine where the files that need to be backed up are stored (the source machine), then running a cron job on another machine (the backup machine), which connects to the source machine and copies (or rsync's) the files that need to be backed up.  You might also want to include a job on the backup machine that preserves changed files for versioning purposes (hard links are good for this).

By allowing connections from the backup machine to the source machine, but not vice-versa - this addresses the security concern that you described in your question.  Even if an attacker gains access to your source machine, he would not be able to connect to the backup machine to destroy your backups.  Versioning on the backup machine provides another layer of protection, in case backed-up files on the backup machine are overwritten by files copied over from the source machine which had been modified by an attacker.  Also, you can make the solution more secure by only allowing SSH connections from the backup machine's IP address, and requiring key-based authentication by the backup machine.